# Getting null array first and then getting actual result in php

Tags: php, arrays, json

In my script i am fetching data from database and storing it in array and output it in json. Everything is going correct just the first array I am getting is null and then the second array has the correct data. I don't understand why am I getting first null array.

My problem solves if I get correct result in array without the null array. 
Here is the output I am getting

```
[[],{"url":"example.com\/sign_pdf\/PDFSign.pdf","name":"PDFSign.pdf","signer":"aman","sequence":"1","message":"Hello","flag":"0"}]
```

I don't need First null array. Why the hell am I getting that.

Here is the code.

```
if(($_GET['action'])&&($_GET['username'])&&($_GET['key'])) {
    $select = $_GET['action'];
    $username =$_GET['username']; //no default
    $key= $_GET['key'];

    if($key=='abcxyz'){
        if($select=='select'){
            /* connect to the db */
            $connect = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','')or die("Couldn't connect to database!");
            mysqli_select_db($connect,'sign') or die ("Couldn't find database");         

            $query ="SELECT * FROM path WHERE signer ='$username' ";

            $result = mysqli_query($connect,$query);
            $numrows=mysqli_num_rows($result);
            $posts[] = array();

            if($numrows!==0) {

                while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
                    $post['url'] = $row['url'];
                    $post['name'] = $row['name'];
                    $post['signer'] = $row['signer'];
                    $post['sequence'] = $row['sequence'];
                    $post['message'] = $row['message'];
                    $post['flag'] = $row['flag'];
                    array_push($posts, $post);
                }

                header('Content-type: application/json');
                echo json_encode($posts); 

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Instead of $posts[] = array(); use $posts = array();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating `array(array())` by `$posts[] = array();`

Replace this:

```
$posts[] = array();
```

with

```
$posts = array();
```

`$posts = array();` will create a null `array()` and not `array(array())`

Answer (score 1):

Your `$posts[]=array()` should be like `$posts=array()` And append `$post` into `$posts` using `$posts[]=$post` .

```
$posts = array();
if ($numrows !== 0) {
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        $post = array();
        $post['url'] = $row['url'];
        $post['name'] = $row['name'];
        $post['signer'] = $row['signer'];
        $post['sequence'] = $row['sequence'];
        $post['message'] = $row['message'];
        $post['flag'] = $row['flag'];
        $posts[] = $post;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
$posts[] = array();
```

Which assigns an array to the first element of `$posts`, use

```
$posts = array();
```

Which initialises the variable, what I think you are trying to do.

Comment: Or, leave that line out as its not required.

Answer (score 0):

You should remove the **$posts** array. The array_push($posts, $post) is basically taking your empty $posts array and adding the $post array to it.